# not got data from database using getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock in parse in ios

Tags: ios

I am using Parse Frame work for storing and retrieving data from database. I want to retrive data from database. For this I am using this getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock. But I am not getting data from database.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"tblContacts"];
[query orderByDescending:@"name"];   
 [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        _arrName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[object valueForKey:@"name"]];
            NSLog(@"name : %@",_arrName);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried by this way. Then I got data from database.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"tblContacts"];
    [query selectKeys:@[@"name"]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        _arrName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[objects valueForKey:@"name"]];
        NSLog(@"name : %@",_arrName);
        [_tblConatcts reloadData];
    }];
```